# C# dynamic acceptable use

Tags: c#

So I have a choice to make regarding 'object' or 'dynamic'.

Would dynamic be an acceptable/viable to use?

I've kept the code short, so please ignore any Runtime exceptions such as null propertyName and null newValue or index not found for dictionary.

What I do know:

1. oldValue and newValue will be the same Type as each other.
2. propertyName will always give the same Type. (Always comparing same Types)
3. Additional checks and operations will be carried out depending on type.
4. oldValue and newValue could be Value or Reference types.

Calling:

```
public int Index
{
    get { return _Index; }
    set
    {
        if (_Index == value) return;

        int oldValue = _Index;

        _Index = value;

        OnChanged(oldValue, value);
    }
}
private int _Index;

public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (_Name == value) return;

        string oldValue = _Name;
        _Name = value;

        OnChanged(oldValue, value);
    }
}
private string _Name;
```

Example 1:

```
private Dictionary<string, dynamic> ModifiedValues = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

protected internal virtual void OnChanged(dynamic oldValue, dynamic newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (ModifiedValues[propertyName] == newValue)
        ModifiedValues.Remove(propertyName);
    else
        ModifiedValues[propertyName] = newValue;

    //...
}
```

Example 2:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> ModifiedValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

protected internal virtual void OnChanged(object oldValue, object newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (newValue.GetType().IsValueType)
    {
        if (newValue.Equals(ModifiedValues[propertyName]))
            ModifiedValues.Remove(propertyName);
        else
            ModifiedValues[propertyName] = newValue;

    }
    else
    {
        if (newValue == ModifiedValues[propertyName])
            ModifiedValues.Remove(propertyName);
        else
            ModifiedValues[propertyName] = newValue;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: you can checkout my answer for a better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

The object class in C# represents the System.Object type, which is the root type in the C# class hierarchy. Generally we use this class when we cannot specify the object type at compile time, which generally happens, when we deal with interoperability.

The dynamic type was introduced in C# 4.0. The dynamic type uses System.Object indirectly but it does not require explicit type casting for any operation at runtime, because it identifies the types at runtime only.

according to above definitions dynamic are acceptable in your case.